# How to control DatePicker height?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, height, datetimepicker

My question is how to set DateTimePicker control height in C# code? I know how to do this for ComboBox but I need help with DatetTimePicker? In some cells of the datagridview control, my program calls the datetimepicker control and needs that control to have the height of the datagridview cell.
How to call funcion like this below?

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, Int32 wParam, Int32 lParam);
    private const Int32 CB_SETITEMHEIGHT = 0x153;

    private void SetComboBoxHeight(IntPtr comboBoxHandle, Int32 comboBoxDesiredHeight)
    {
        SendMessage(comboBoxHandle, CB_SETITEMHEIGHT, -1, comboBoxDesiredHeight);
    }
```

Comment: It is unclear why you are reaching out to the OS to resize the control. You could try setting the `DateTimePicker`’s `MinimumSize` property to set the height… something like … `dateTimePicker1.MinimumSize = new Size(208, 200);`

Comment: This option works well. Thanks.